# Sqlite SUM sub query issue

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying this query for my android app, this works fine with mysql but doesnt give proper results with sqlite

```
SELECT cust.Name,cust.ID,billNo,billTime,
(SELECT SUM(b.qty*b.Price*(SELECT (1+(s.tax/100))FROM tbl_stock s 
WHERE b.itemCode=s.itemCode)) 
FROM tbl_billitems b WHERE a.billNo=b.billNo AND a.terminal=b.terminal)AS total ,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_billitems c WHERE a.billNo=c.billNo 
AND a.terminal=c.terminal),terminal FROM tbl_bills a, tbl_customers cust 
WHERE a.ID=cust.ID AND a.billNo IN (SELECT billNo from tbl_billitems)
```

it gives correct value with mysql but in sqlite is only giving the sum of (b.qty*b.Price)

Please guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: Create an example in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score -1):

This is my app code..hope u have got some idea..

```
 SELECT t.*, ((summeJ-summeVJ)/summeVJ*100) AS variance
 FROM (SELECT k.ZKUNDENNR, k.ZNAME1,
         (SELECT SUM(vk.ZNETTO) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2013 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) AS summeJ,
         (SELECT SUM(vk.ZNETTO) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2012 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeVJ,
         (SELECT SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2012 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeDBVJ,
         (SELECT SUM(vk.ZDB_BASIS) FROM ZPBSROW r LEFT JOIN ZWARENGRUPPEVK vk ON vk.ZPBSROW=r.Z_PK WHERE r.ZKUNDE=k.Z_PK AND ZJAHR=2013 AND ZMONAT>=1 AND ZMONAT<=6) as summeDBJ
  FROM ZKUNDE k
 ) t
WHERE summeJ>0
ORDER BY summeJ DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: How is this related to the problem?